# Unknown error in Producer/Consumer program, believe it to be an infinite loop

Tags: c, unix, consumer, producer

I am writing a program that is solving the producer/consumer problem, specifically the bounded-buffer version(i believe they mean the same thing). The producer will be generating x number of random numbers, where x is a command line parameter to my program. At the current moment, I believe my program is entering an infinite loop, but I'm not sure why it is occurring. I believe I am executing the semaphores correctly.

You compile it like this:
gcc -o prodcon prodcon.cpp -lpthread -lrt
Then to run, ./prodcon 100(the number of randum nums to produce)

This is my code.

```
 typedef int buffer_item;

 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <pthread.h>
 #include <semaphore.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 #define BUFF_SIZE 10
 #define RAND_DIVISOR 100000000
 #define TRUE 1

 //two threads
 void *Producer(void *param);  
 void *Consumer(void *param);

 int insert_item(buffer_item item);
 int remove_item(buffer_item *item);
 int returnRandom();


 //the global semaphores

 sem_t empty, full, mutex;

 //the buffer

 buffer_item buf[BUFF_SIZE];

 //buffer counter
 int counter;

 //number of random numbers to produce
 int numRand;

 int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 /* thread ids and attributes */
 pthread_t pid, cid;  
 pthread_attr_t attr;
 pthread_attr_init(&attr);
 pthread_attr_setscope(&attr, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);

 numRand = atoi(argv[1]);
 sem_init(&empty,0,BUFF_SIZE);
 sem_init(&full,0,0);
 sem_init(&mutex,0,0);

 printf("main started\n");
 pthread_create(&pid, &attr, Producer, NULL);
 pthread_create(&cid, &attr, Consumer, NULL);
 printf("main gets here");
 pthread_join(pid, NULL);
 pthread_join(cid, NULL);
 printf("main done\n");

 return 0;

 }

 //generates a randum number between 1 and 100
 int returnRandom()
 {
  int num;
  srand(time(NULL));
  num = rand() % 100 + 1;
  return num;
 }

 //begin producing items
 void *Producer(void *param) {
    buffer_item item;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < numRand; i++)
    {
     //sleep for a random period of time
     int rNum = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR;
     sleep(rNum);

     //generate a random number
     item = returnRandom();

     //acquire the empty lock
     sem_wait(&empty);

     //acquire the mutex lock
     sem_wait(&mutex);

      if(insert_item(item)) 
      {
     fprintf(stderr, " Producer report error condition\n");
      }
      else 
      {
     printf("producer produced %d\n", item);
      }
      /* release the mutex lock */
     sem_post(&mutex);
     /* signal full */
     sem_post(&full);
    }
    return NULL;
 }

 /* Consumer Thread */
 void *Consumer(void *param) {
    buffer_item item;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < numRand; i++) {
    /* sleep for a random period of time */
    int rNum = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR;
    sleep(rNum);

    /* aquire the full lock */
    sem_wait(&full);
    /* aquire the mutex lock */
    sem_wait(&mutex);
    if(remove_item(&item)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Consumer report error condition\n");
    }
    else {
    printf("consumer consumed %d\n", item);
    }
    /* release the mutex lock */
    sem_post(&mutex);
    /* signal empty */
    sem_post(&empty);
    }
    return NULL;
 }

  /* Add an item to the buffer */
 int insert_item(buffer_item item) {
    /* When the buffer is not full add the item
    and increment the counter*/
    if(counter < BUFF_SIZE) {
    buf[counter] = item;
    counter++;
    return 0;
    }
    else { /* Error the buffer is full */
    return -1;
    }
 }

 /* Remove an item from the buffer */
 int remove_item(buffer_item *item) {
    /* When the buffer is not empty remove the item
    and decrement the counter */
    if(counter > 0) {
    *item = buf[(counter-1)];
    counter--;
    return 0;
    }
    else { /* Error buffer empty */
    return -1;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Look [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1601/sync-11157.html#sync-27385) for an abstract of this problem

Answer (score 0):

```
 sem_init(&empty,0,BUFF_SIZE);
 sem_init(&full,0,0);
```

Try initializing the "mutex" semaphore here as well.

Comment: sem_init(&mutex,0,1);

this is what torak is talking about.  If you initialize it to zero then when "Producer" tries to acquire the semaphore it gets blocked (the "infinite loop" behavior that you saw).

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the mutex to 1.
Try commenting out the calls to sleep (i don't have an explanation, except "it works for me").
Edit : sleep takes a number of seconds, it may look blocked because the random number is too high.

Call srand in your main (otherwise you'll get identical values, as you seed again with the same time).

Comment: It seems to be working now, thanks everyone! The sleep was way too high I believe. When my assignment said to sleep between 1 and 10 seconds.